# Getting "Suspicious request" every time I log in

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, suspicious-request

Since the first time I tried log in to Stack Overflow with the new login form I always get

> Suspicious request
>
> Sorry, your request could not be completed because
> it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack
> Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again.

[image]

Anyway it logs me in.

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

The OpenID provider I'm using is Stack Exchange's.

I'm using Firefox Nightly 43.0a1 with some extensions, but I tried also with Chrome 46.0.2490.4 dev-m without plugins and Internet Explorer 9, and I get the same message.

I also have to press login button (or press enter) twice, otherwise I don't get any response from the website and sometime (more than one time per hour) I have logged out, and I need to log in again.

Comment: This happened to me once (not every time).

Comment: Happens randomly. I use Google + login.

Comment: Your question seems a little suspicious

Comment: Could some plugin be the culprit? Have you tried disabling your plugins (or trying another browser altogether)?

Comment: I had the same issue when loggin in with google+. This was happening last week but since this week its working fine

Comment: @TobiaTesan I updated the post adding required info

Comment: If you log in a lot you might make it to the baseline!

Comment: Are you using a vpn?

Comment: @hitch.united I'm not using a VPN

Comment: @Holmes I'm a Stackoverflow user since more than 2 years and I've never had any kind of problem with other users or administrators. What is suspicious in my question?

Comment: @codroipo this must be your first time on meta then, jokes actually do happen here ;)

Comment: @codroipo: have you tried logging in using a stable browser version? Do you get any errors or messages in the console either when the login page loads, or when you submit your login request?

Comment: @Matt Same behavior with IE9

Comment: Are you using https or http?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: I see this occasionally when trying to login to SE sites I don't frequent. Got no data, only this little tale.

Comment: What about using a *common* browser? Not just the newest or oldest? ;-) A vanilla setup is known to (mostly) work "best".

Comment: Are you using tor?

Comment: Happens to me every time using google login, but only HTTP. Works fine with HTTPS

Comment: @rene I'm using http, just tried https and it works fine!

Comment: @RossAllan What do you mean? All our login pages and requests are (should be?) happening over HTTPS already. Where are you ending up on HTTP?

Comment: Completely unrelated: are you from [Codroipo in Friuli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codroipo)? I live ~40km from there.

Comment: @TravisJ I hope not.

Comment: @AnnaLear This was with meta.electronics.stackexchange.com - I'm already logged into my stackexchange account and it works on the HTTPS sites. When on that meta site which has no HTTPS, I am a logged out user. Clicking log in -> suspicious request. The login is by clicking the "sign up with google" on the login dialog which pops up when you try to vote. I can try again on Monday, works fine at home. Could be a dodgy proxy at work.

Comment: @RossAllan That... shouldn't matter. We don't fully support HTTPS everywhere yet, so that may be part of the problem here, but you should be logged in on both main and meta regardless of the protocol you're using. Clicking "log in" on meta should redirect you to the main site's login page since you can't log into a child meta directly. Feel free to email me directly (email's in my profile, screenshots are helpful :)) so we don't hijack this comment thread.

Comment: @AnnaLear Don't know if can help, but I noticed that if I go to the login page (which is always HTTPS) from a stackoverflow's HTTP page the login give me the suspicious request. If I go to it from a stackoverflow's HTTPS page the login responds quickly and the login works correctly

Comment: @Bakuriu No, I'm Italian, but not from Friuli, I chose codroipo because it has a curious anagram...

Comment: @codroipo I see what you did there...

Comment: @AnnaLear Did you get my email? I sent screenshots of the suspicious request issue as requested.

Comment: @RossAllan Yes, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still an issue? AFAIK, Adam looked into it and a few code fixes were deployed. Can I close this as [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Oded Now I noticed that login is always in HTTPS, so I don't get the suspicious request(also in past when logging in with HTTPS I didn't receive the error)

Comment: Yeah, login has been HTTPS only for quite some time now. Closing this then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, this is fun. It may or may not be related to new login stuff: we really aren't sure, since we can't reproduce this behaviour.

One thing that we did see in the traffic logs is that clicking the "log in" button multiple times can result in the second request being considered suspicious if the first request takes a long time to complete. By the time your second submission goes through, the first one is far enough along that the second attempt is considered invalid. My advice there would be to click the button once and give it time to finish.

The other common case for suspicious request reports is when someone's IP address changes mid-process. This isn't your specific case as far as I can tell, but I'm mentioning it for completeness' sake. That behaviour is intentional.

We're looking further into this, but it may be a bit before we are able to figure it out. Step one - moar logging to try and establish a pattern. I'll update this answer if/when we find anything.

Comment: This happened to me today. IP addresses get changed midway before getting to the destination URL.

Answer (score 10):

We, in my team, encountered this already, and this is the summary of our experience (it may be different to yours; this is on a case-to-case basis):

---

#### Multiple Log-in:

1. I logged into Stack Overflow using my PC.
2. I went to another room (we had a meeting) and randomly used a PC there. Since my friend was logged in already on that PC, I opened an *incognito* browser and logged in. (I forgot that I was already logged on to my own PC.)
3. Attempted for like 15 minutes, and since I could not, I returned furiously to my workstation.
4. And voila, I instantly realized that the reason why I couldn't log on to my friend's PC was that I was logged in to my PC.

---

#### Mobile devices:

- My friend tested this on his account by logging on a PC while still being logged on to his mobile device (and the other way around). Sometimes it failed, and sometimes it didn't, he said.

---

#### Cache:

- Try clearing your browser's cache and retry logging again.

Comment: 1. About Multiple Log-In: I'm using only a PC and the account credentials are not known by other people(I think....) 2. I never used stackoverflow with mobile devices 3. Just tried clearing cache, but behavior is the same

Comment: I am always logged in at 3 different computers running different operating systems and browsers. There never was a problem.

Comment: I'm always logged in with the following: 1. Work PC, 2. Home PC, 3. Laptop, 4. Tablet, 5. Phone. I've never had any issues.

Comment: Another member of the "I'm always logged in on at least two computers" chorus here. StackExchange has no problem with one person using multiple computers; it goes kablooey if multiple people try to use one computer. Various changes to the login process over the years have improved things somewhat, but I still refuse to log in to SE from public computers, because I'm never 100% certain that I'll be able to log out.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this same problem now. 
I'm logged in on only one computer.

I just deleted all the specific cookies related to stack* from the browser in Chrome. Then (very important) I opened a new tab to Stackoveflow.com and could authenticate.

Note: If you try refreshing your existing Stackoverflow page where you failed to login previously, the problem persists. So use a new tab.