# "Suspicious request" message after login

Tags: support, login

After I log in, I'm redirected to this page stating *"Suspicious request"*.

I don't know what it is. Did I do something wrong? I just logged in at stackoverflow.com.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170875/suspicious-login-request-when-using-google-id and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303580/getting-suspicious-request-every-time-i-log-in

Comment: Does this happen every time you log in? Or just this one time?

Comment: Reload the page and the XSS warning will most likely vanish.

Comment: @Oded this happen only once.

Comment: Yeah, that can happen, if sessions go out of sync. Nothing bad on your end - feel free to ignore (unless it happens all the time).

Comment: If you have nothing to hide, you have nothing to fear from the suspicious request page.