# Asking question, got "Suspicious request - Stack Overflow"

Tags: feature-request, bug, suspicious-request

I can't post a question, because I get this error:

> Suspicious request - Stack Overflow

I had to check in network responses to find out about this message. The UX was really bad in that particular case; it would just say "An error occurred submitting the question".

As a feature request, that would be great if the UI could provide a better error message.

The response has a 418 HTTP code, and its content is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">

<head>

<title>Suspicious request - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

See the post content at https://pastebin.com/bt6EEY0x

As a bug, next time I get this error, and for that particular case,
how can Stack Overflow provide more detailed information about this problem so the end user is more autonomous in understanding/finding and fixing the problem in his post?

Comment: This has happened before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303580/getting-suspicious-request-every-time-i-log-in